# Unable to add components in layout in Sitecore 10.2 Experience editor

Tags: sitecore-client

We have upgraded our site from `Sitecore 9.1 to Sitecore 10.2`. Post upgrade we started facing issue on the Experience editor as follow,
Problem statement: Whenever we tried to add a new component to the Experience editor, we are getting an `Error Occurred` popup with the following error stack.

```
15728 11:18:28 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: placeholderKey
Source: Sitecore.ExperienceEditor
at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.InsertRendering.Process(PipelineArgs args)
at (Object , Object )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.ExecutePageEditorActionPipeline.Run(ExecutePageEditorActionArgs args)
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Palette.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `this.chrome.openingMarker().attr("phkey")` with OR condition in `PlaceholderKey` function in

`\sitecore\shell\Applications\Page Modes\ChromeTypes\PlaceholderChromeType.js`

file solved my issue. The code snippet is as follows.

```
placeholderKey: function() 
        {
            return this.chrome.openingMarker().attr("key") ||
            this.chrome.openingMarker().attr("phkey");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions I can suggest:

1. If you are using any custom pipeline in your project then use the `resolve="true" attribute`. Custom processors patched into a pipeline now required mandatory attribute resolve.

`<processor type="projectname.Website.Patch.LanguageRedirect, projectname.Website" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" resolve="true" />`

2. Please verify the DLL version in your project, It should be the same in your vanilla Sitecore 10.2 instance and in your project code.